# System.InvalidOperationException при получении пикселя

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Код выполняется в отдельном потоке, вычисляет средний цвет изображения и рисует его на Control'е. При получении цвета пикселя `_bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, _bmp.Width, _bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, _bmp.PixelFormat);` выходит сообщение: `System.InvalidOperationException in System.Drawing.dll В данный момент объект используется другим процессом`.

```
private void SomeThread()
{
    //..
    Thread th0 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(TH_showArt_));
    th0.Start(Puth_);
}


private void TH_showArt_(object puth_)
{
    String Puth_ = puth_.ToString();
    Image img64x64 = Image.FromFile(Puth_);

    //..

    //Считается средний цвет изображения
    string[] MD_C = MPLAY.Lib.BitmapClass.Middle_RGB_str((Bitmap)img64x64).Split(';');

    //..
}



public static string Middle_RGB_str(Bitmap Image_) 
{
    string MD_C = "0;0;0";

    var bb = new BufferedBitmap(Image_);

    for (int i = bb.Height - 1; i > -1; i--)
    {
        for (int j = bb.Width - 1; j > -1; j--)
        {
            //Обертка LockBits, здесь кстати и ошибка
            Color clr = bb.GetPixel(i, j);
            //_bmp.LockBits(
            //    new Rectangle(0, 0, _bmp.Width, _bmp.Height),
            //    ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
            //    _bmp.PixelFormat
            //);
            //System.InvalidOperationException in System.Drawing.dll В данный момент объект используется другим процессом.
            //..
        }
    }

    //..

    MD_C = avgR.ToString() + ";" + avgG.ToString() + ";" + avgB.ToString();

    return MD_C;
}
```

Что можно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Вы параллельно используете `_bmp` в каком-то еще потоке (скорее всего, в главном). Ищите, где. `Bitmap` не поддерживает многопоточную работу, поэтому вам надо либо синхронизировать доступ к нему, либо работать с его копией.

Comment: Все что связано с bitmap идет в отдельно потоке, не в основном, а решение было самое тупое. я добавил строку `BitmapData _bd;` перед `var bb = new BufferedBitmap(Image_);` ошибку как рукой смахнуло.